# Java 7 Server SE JRE installation

Tags: security, java

I want to install Java 7 Server SE JRE on a Windows server box.  Reading through the instructions here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/server-jre-installation-windows.html

It says to:
The Server JRE files are installed in a directory called jdk1.7.0_ in the current directory.

However, there's a lot of stuff in that tar file.  I just want to use the jre folder right under jdk1.7.0_.

Can I just copy over /jdk1.7.0_/jre and it's subfolders?  Are there any downstream impacts I should be aware of, in terms of security and performance?  Or any other issues besides the loss of functionality?

Ultimately, I want to point Tomcat to jre/bin/server/jvm.dll.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Server JRE" tarball (I'm referring to [this download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html)) file is a complete JDK/JRE bundle, and as such, should go to its own directory. The tar file contains the top level directory, so if you simply unpack the file, you'll have a fully functional JDK/JRE.

So you shouldn't copy the contents to an existing JRE or JDK directory. Just unpack the file, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It sounds like you're saying that "Server JRE" tarball has more than what's needed to just run a server on.  So I just took the JRE folder and it seems to be running fine right now.  Thanks.